# Are frontend templated websites dynamic or static?

Tags: javascript, terminology

I am currently building a project, which is a survey creator. I created a Rest API on the backend with pure Node.js, and am also working on the frontend.
Obviously, rendered pages need to be rendered depending whether a user is logged in or not, the current survey, etc. Normally, I use Express.js and integrate a template engine like Pug. However this project was designed to be as dependency-less as possible, so no template engines. Instead I simply send "static" HTML files to the client when the user sends a request. Then, on the frontend, I use template strings to "fill in" HTML like this:

```js
document.querySelector('cta').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<div class="login" style=${isLoggedIn? "display: none;" : ""}`); // etc.
```

This made me wonder if I am really building a dynamic website. Technically, I am "dynamically" generating the HTML?

But there seem to be conflicting messages from the [Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_web_page) and a Udemy course, both which seem to say that dynamic websites are generated on the server side like this:

```
When user hits request:
Backend builds template --> compiled to html --> file served to user
```

The way I do it looks like this:

```
Html file served --> JavaScript generates html
```

The terminology is very important here - is my website dynamic or static?

Comment: You are using JS to fetch dynamic data. This is kind of like a Single page application. There are special frameworks and libraries for this too like react, vue, angular. VanillaJS like your example is fine too but code smartly, otherwise you will get slow in long run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: it is a hybrid page. If you do not care on SEO it may be redundant to worry about such things, just do in a way that convenient for you.

So, your thinking way is valid, if you provide clients with the page which contents never changes on the client's side - it is the static page. You may show/hide the existing pre-rendered elements (like changing `style` attribute from `display: none;`). Any manipulations with shadow DOM or attaching HTML elements on the runtime promotes the page from "static" to dynamical or hybrid page.

Next, if you navigate to a new page on your website and you see the browser fetches a new `.html` file for the new page to display, it is a mark for the static page. But, if contents of the fetched page are changed afterwards by the script of your website on the client side the page cannot be called "static" anymore, is more like hybrid or dynamic page. Re-rendering the same page is about single-page-applications, all the pages of it are pure dynamic pages.

The main point why we care about is it static page, dynamic page, or hybrid page is SEO optimisation. Web crawlers analyze your page contents to detect what is your page about, to show later in Google, Bing, etc. The crawlers may (and mostly will) analyze your dynamical content in a bit unexpected way for you, so some your target audience risk never see your page. Thus, if you need the crawlers to analyze your page as "internet toy shop" you should fetch all the promotional and descriptional contents from the server and never change it afterwards. If you are making something like users personal cabinet, you can omit worrying on such stuff and just generate contents on the client's side.

Comment: @expressjs123 also, a bit more to say on the static and dynamic page differences:

Comment: you may consider the size of the page. For SPA, it is general stuff if the only page takes up to 5 MB and more. Some applications do not care about it if the page is served to "strong" PCs or is a game page, etc. But if it is an internet shop, your page should take as fewer resources as possible, thus most of the internet shops are hybrid websites. There are a tiny amount of pure static websites; Wikipedia is the most popular example of a static website. You can try to analyze how fast it is served.

Answer (score 0):

As long as it works without the JS I would say that it is a static website with progressive enhancement, as the pages are not generated by the server on each request and then JS (if enabled) is used the provide additional non essential features or functionality.

Answer (score 0):

> A static website contains Web pages with fixed content. Each page is coded in HTML and displays the same information to every visitor. Static sites are the most basic type of website and are the easiest to create. Unlike dynamic websites, they do not require any Web programming or database design. A static site can be built by simply creating a few HTML pages and publishing them to a Web server.

[Source](https://techterms.com/definition/staticwebsite)

So in my opinion plain html without any frontend, any backend generation is static website, what you describing is dynamic website.
So it is something very basic, consider it as generated pdf, you cannot change it, in order to modify it you would need to go to file edit it, save, and then publish to end users

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>My static website</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p> Static means no process </p>
</body>
</html>
```